# Get the "key" of an object in Actionscript-3

Tags: actionscript-3, object

Given an Object:

`myObj = {key : 'value'}`

How do I get the key?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You have to loop through the all the keys

```
for (var key:String in myObj) {
 //...
}
```

Note: `for(x in obj)` iterates over the keys, while `for each(x in obj)` iterates over the values.

Comment: wouldn't wouldn't key = 'value'?

Comment: @DerekAdair No, `for(x in obj)` iterates over the keys, while `for each(x in obj)` iterates over the values.  It's confusing syntax.

Answer (score 11):

Use a `for in` loop

```
var myObject:Object = {key1:"value1",key2:"value2"}

for (var s:String in myObject){
  trace("key:",s,"value:",myObject[s]);
}
```

output:

```
key: key1 value: value1
key: key2 value: value2
```