# List All Variables in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables

I'm trying to list the all variables in AS3 with the value. I want to do this because my code is getting some random number somewhere. Really, all I want to see is when the code gets the random number and I think listing it with the value at random points will help me find out what's messing it up.

I know you can do this in AS2 using:

```
for(var i in MovieClip){
    trace(i+":"+this[i]);
}
```

How can you do the same thing with AS3?

Comment: https://manikmagar.wordpress.com/2009/09/20/iterate-through-actionscript-object-properties-as-reflection/

Comment: I don't think that's a great approach to debugging the problem. Have a think about where the random number might be being set or generated. If you can isolate the problem you can set a breakpoint or use a trace statement to figure out why you're getting the random number. I honestly can't think what you would learn from what you're attempting to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the "key" of an object in Actionscript-3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427284/get-the-key-of-an-object-in-actionscript-3)