# get key of a object at index x

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

How to get the key at specified index of a object in Flex?

```
var screenWindowListObject:Object = {
  'something' : 'awesome',
  'evenmore'  : 'crazy',
  'evenless'  : 'foolish'
};
```

I want key at index 1 i.e `evenmore`.

In JavaScript it can be possible by using the following code.

```
var keys = Object.keys(screenWindowListObject);
console.log(keys[1]);   // gives output 'evenmore'
```

Is there any equivalent in Flex?

I have an object with unique keys. Values are not unique. I am displaying the values in DropDownList by adding them to an Array Collection. I have to get the key from the Object based on the selected index.

Comment: This is a weird question because those keys aren't in any particular order at runtime.

Comment: Could you tell us why you want this? There is probably a better solution for your usecase. For example, to get all the keys of a object, refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427284/get-the-key-of-an-object-in-actionscript-3)

Comment: If you need an index use array or vector, if you don't need an index use Object (cos you'll never get one with Object)

Comment: @Vishnu Take a look on [my answer of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27670274/2256820), may be it can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Adobe, "[Object properties are not kept in any particular order, so properties may appear in a seemingly random order.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#for..in)"  Because of this, you'll have to invent your own order.  This can be achieved by populating an array with your keys, and then sorting that.

```
function getKeyOrder(hash:Object, sortType:int = 3):Array {
    // Returns an array with sorted key values.
    /*
        1 = CASEINSENSITIVE
        2 = DESCENDING
        3 = ASCENDING
        4 = UNIQUESORT
        8 = RETURNINDEXEDARRAY
        16 = Array.NUMERIC
    */
    var order:Array = [];
    for (var k:String in hash) {
        order.push(k);
    }

    var reverse:Boolean = false;
    if (sortType == 3) {
        reverse = true;
        sortType = 2;
    }

    order.sort(sortType)
    if (reverse) { order.reverse(); }

    return order;
}


var screenWindowListObject:Object = {
    'something' : 'awesome',
    'evenmore'  : 'crazy',
    'evenless'  : 'foolish'
};

var orderedKeys:Array = getKeyOrder(screenWindowListObject);
for each (var key in orderedKeys) {
    trace(key + ":" + screenWindowListObject[key]);
}
/* Results in...
    evenless:foolish
    evenmore:crazy
    something:awesome
*/

trace("Index 0 = " + screenWindowListObject[orderedKeys[0]])
// Index 0 = foolish
```

`getKeyOrder()` returns an array with your keys in ascending order by default.  This way, you'll be guaranteed to always have the same sequence of keys, and be able to pull up the index you're looking for.  Just be wary when adding more keys, as it will shift each entry depending on where it shows up in the sort.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript's [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) uses the same order as a `for..in` loop, so in AS3 you could implement it the same way:

```
function getKeys(object:Object):Array {
    var keys:Array = [];
    for(var key in object){
        keys.push(key);
    }
    return keys;
}
```

Note, though, that the enumerable order of keys on an object at runtime is not necessarily the same as you've written it in code.